# "The Resurrection Psalm" - should we interpret Psalm 23 in the context of Psalms 22 / 24?

Tags: psalms, context

Recently I encountered the concept that some call Psalm 23 ["the Resurrection Psalm",](http://file:///C:/Users/steve.taylor/Downloads/fulltext_stamped.pdf) which as far as I can ascertain is primarily due to its location between Psalm 22 (referenced by Christ at the crucifixion) and Psalm 24 (ascension / new kingdom), which is taken as context for interpretation.

Is such a reading hermeneutically valid? To what degree should Psalms 22 and 24 impact the way we read Psalm 23?

Answer (score 1):

They are all Psalms of David and are, presumably, in an order that reflects David's contribution to the collection of Psalms as a whole.

But Psalm 22 has a definitive title which Psalms 23 and 24 lack.

My own conclusion would be that the evidence for attaching such a significance as resurrection to Psalm 23 ought to come from within the psalm itself.

It appears to me to be fanciful, otherwise. And, thus, unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Psalm 22 contains its own reference to the Resurrection, in verse 22, which is quoted by the author of Hebrews, in chapter 2:12, as follows:

Psalm 22:22 (KJV)

22. I will declare thy name unto my brethren: in the midst of the congregation will I praise thee.

Hebrews 2:12 (KJV),

12. Saying, I will declare thy name unto my brethren, in the midst of the church will I sing praise unto thee.

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+22

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+2&version=KJV

The context of Hebrews 2:12, in the surrounding verses clearly indicate a post-resurrection narrative.

Verses 1-4 speak of those things regarding salvation which both Jesus, then His apostles preached, with signs and wonders following, things that could only happen if Jesus truly rose from the dead and sent the promise of the Father just as He said He would do (See, e.g. Luke 24:49 and Acts 1:5).

Verses 5-8 speak of the world or age to come and how all of that world/age is under the subjection of Christ, which again, happened, not just at His resurrection, but especially at His ascension to the Right Hand of the Father.

Verses 9-11 speak of Christ's human nature, and how, being human allowed Him to suffer and die, to taste death for everyone, which allows Him to call, in the present sense, His followers and disciples, His brethren. Being able to to that in a present sense indicates a raise to life Messiah, not merely someone who died decades earlier, but never rose from the dead.

Verses 13-18, the end of the chapter, continue the theme begun in verses 9-11, fleshing it out and making the strong case that Jesus isn't of the angels, but is to be regarded higher than they.

It becomes clear then that the quotation of Psalm 22:22 in Hebrews 2:12 is meant to be understood within a post-resurrection context.